# Expo app working on Expo Go and iOS Simulator but crashes on real device

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have an iOS Expo based project using the managed workflow. My app runs perfectly fine on the simulator and on Expo Go but on my device (installed with TestFlight) it crashes immediately after seeing the splash screen fade away for a second. Can anyone detect the problem is based on the below logs?

**Expo Diagnostics:**

```
  Expo CLI 5.0.3 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 11.2.3
      Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.22.8 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.11 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 7.6.3 - ~/.npm-packages/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 14.5, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 14.5, watchOS 7.4
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 28
        Build Tools: 28.0.3
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069
      Xcode: 12.5.1/12E507 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      @expo/metro-config: ^0.1.34 => 0.1.84 
      expo: ^44.0.0 => 44.0.5 
      react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
      react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
      react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3 
      react-native-web: 0.17.1 => 0.17.1 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 0.45.1
      expo-cli: 5.0.3
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

**iOS Analytics Log from crash (truncated):**

```
{
  "exception": {
    "codes": "0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000",
    "rawCodes": [
      0,
      0
    ],
    "type": "EXC_CRASH",
    "signal": "SIGABRT"
  },
  "asi": {
    "libsystem_c.dylib": [
      "abort() called"
    ]
  },
  "lastExceptionBacktrace": [
    {
      "imageOffset": 626940,
      "symbol": "__exceptionPreprocess",
      "symbolLocation": 220,
      "imageIndex": 6
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 89444,
      "symbol": "objc_exception_throw",
      "symbolLocation": 60,
      "imageIndex": 16
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 1504572,
      "symbol": "-[NSException init]",
      "symbolLocation": 0,
      "imageIndex": 6
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 4844500,
      "imageIndex": 8
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 4510316,
      "imageIndex": 8
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 10532,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_call_block_and_release",
      "symbolLocation": 32,
      "imageIndex": 11
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 18032,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_client_callout",
      "symbolLocation": 20,
      "imageIndex": 11
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 30616,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_queue_override_invoke",
      "symbolLocation": 792,
      "imageIndex": 11
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 89568,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_root_queue_drain",
      "symbolLocation": 396,
      "imageIndex": 11
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 91656,
      "symbol": "_dispatch_worker_thread2",
      "symbolLocation": 164,
      "imageIndex": 11
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 4280,
      "symbol": "_pthread_wqthread",
      "symbolLocation": 228,
      "imageIndex": 10
    },
    {
      "imageOffset": 3732,
      "symbol": "start_wqthread",
      "symbolLocation": 8,
      "imageIndex": 10
    }
  ],
  "faultingThread": 6,
  "threads": [
    {
      "id": 10147,
      "queue": "com.apple.main-thread",
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 5380,
          "symbol": "mach_msg_trap",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 0
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 7068,
          "symbol": "mach_msg",
          "symbolLocation": 76,
          "imageIndex": 0
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 13544,
          "symbol": "io_connect_method",
          "symbolLocation": 440,
          "imageIndex": 1
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 10452,
          "symbol": "IOConnectCallMethod",
          "symbolLocation": 236,
          "imageIndex": 1
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 9260,
          "symbol": "IOSurfaceClientCreateChild",
          "symbolLocation": 204,
          "imageIndex": 2
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 24800,
          "symbol": "-[IOSurface initWithProperties:]",
          "symbolLocation": 80,
          "imageIndex": 2
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 82108,
          "symbol": "__csiCompressImageProviderCopyIOSurfaceWithOptions",
          "symbolLocation": 696,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 619780,
          "symbol": "CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double, double)",
          "symbolLocation": 2388,
          "imageIndex": 4
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 949516,
          "symbol": "CA::Render::prepare_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double)",
          "symbolLocation": 24,
          "imageIndex": 4
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 203568,
          "symbol": "CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*)",
          "symbolLocation": 508,
          "imageIndex": 4
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 290700,
          "symbol": "CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)",
          "symbolLocation": 536,
          "imageIndex": 4
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 325748,
          "symbol": "CA::Transaction::commit()",
          "symbolLocation": 680,
          "imageIndex": 4
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 3503484,
          "symbol": "__34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2",
          "symbolLocation": 44,
          "imageIndex": 5
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 469460,
          "symbol": "__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__",
          "symbolLocation": 28,
          "imageIndex": 6
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 473296,
          "symbol": "__CFRunLoopDoBlocks",
          "symbolLocation": 412,
          "imageIndex": 6
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 47288,
          "symbol": "__CFRunLoopRun",
          "symbolLocation": 840,
          "imageIndex": 6
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 128104,
          "symbol": "CFRunLoopRunSpecific",
          "symbolLocation": 600,
          "imageIndex": 6
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 5004,
          "symbol": "GSEventRunModal",
          "symbolLocation": 164,
          "imageIndex": 7
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 5349512,
          "symbol": "-[UIApplication _run]",
          "symbolLocation": 1100,
          "imageIndex": 5
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 2722136,
          "symbol": "UIApplicationMain",
          "symbolLocation": 2092,
          "imageIndex": 5
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 28096,
          "imageIndex": 8
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 105124,
          "symbol": "start",
          "symbolLocation": 520,
          "imageIndex": 9
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10153,
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 3724,
          "symbol": "start_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 0,
          "imageIndex": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10154,
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 3724,
          "symbol": "start_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 0,
          "imageIndex": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10155,
      "queue": "com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement",
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 8612,
          "symbol": "__ulock_wait",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 0
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 20580,
          "symbol": "_dlock_wait",
          "symbolLocation": 56,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 19976,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow",
          "symbolLocation": 56,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 80812,
          "symbol": "__DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__",
          "symbolLocation": 364,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 79700,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_sync_f_slow",
          "symbolLocation": 144,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 3615556,
          "symbol": "__37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3",
          "symbolLocation": 136,
          "imageIndex": 5
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 140196,
          "symbol": "__invoking___",
          "symbolLocation": 148,
          "imageIndex": 6
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 260980,
          "symbol": "-[NSInvocation invoke]",
          "symbolLocation": 468,
          "imageIndex": 6
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 216976,
          "symbol": "__NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__",
          "symbolLocation": 24,
          "imageIndex": 12
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 352068,
          "symbol": "-[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:]",
          "symbolLocation": 572,
          "imageIndex": 12
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 199444,
          "symbol": "__88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3",
          "symbolLocation": 212,
          "imageIndex": 12
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 115500,
          "symbol": "_xpc_connection_reply_callout",
          "symbolLocation": 116,
          "imageIndex": 13
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 63580,
          "symbol": "_xpc_connection_call_reply_async",
          "symbolLocation": 88,
          "imageIndex": 13
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 18160,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_client_callout3",
          "symbolLocation": 20,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 138968,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke",
          "symbolLocation": 348,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 48332,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_lane_serial_drain",
          "symbolLocation": 376,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 51612,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_lane_invoke",
          "symbolLocation": 444,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 94648,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread",
          "symbolLocation": 656,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 4340,
          "symbol": "_pthread_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 288,
          "imageIndex": 10
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 3732,
          "symbol": "start_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10156,
      "name": "com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread",
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 5380,
          "symbol": "mach_msg_trap",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 0
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 7068,
          "symbol": "mach_msg",
          "symbolLocation": 76,
          "imageIndex": 0
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 30520,
          "symbol": "__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort",
          "symbolLocation": 372,
          "imageIndex": 6
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 47660,
          "symbol": "__CFRunLoopRun",
          "symbolLocation": 1212,
          "imageIndex": 6
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 128104,
          "symbol": "CFRunLoopRunSpecific",
          "symbolLocation": 600,
          "imageIndex": 6
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 101524,
          "symbol": "-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]",
          "symbolLocation": 236,
          "imageIndex": 12
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 368072,
          "symbol": "-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]",
          "symbolLocation": 92,
          "imageIndex": 12
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 4796976,
          "symbol": "-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]",
          "symbolLocation": 524,
          "imageIndex": 5
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 427020,
          "symbol": "__NSThread__start__",
          "symbolLocation": 808,
          "imageIndex": 12
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 6564,
          "symbol": "_pthread_start",
          "symbolLocation": 148,
          "imageIndex": 10
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 3744,
          "symbol": "thread_start",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10157,
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 3724,
          "symbol": "start_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 0,
          "imageIndex": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "triggered": true,
      "id": 10158,
      "threadState": {
        "x": [
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 6880178349
          },
          {
            "value": 6099020224
          },
          {
            "value": 110
          },
          {
            "value": 1536
          },
          {
            "value": 12602054078030524090
          },
          {
            "value": 12602054081679335098
          },
          {
            "value": 2
          },
          {
            "value": 11
          },
          {
            "value": 3311423497
          },
          {
            "value": 1163939840
          },
          {
            "value": 16
          },
          {
            "value": 2
          },
          {
            "value": 328
          },
          {
            "value": 6099021824
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 6
          },
          {
            "value": 13059
          },
          {
            "value": 6099022048
          },
          {
            "value": 276
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 6099022048
          },
          {
            "value": 7975813572,
            "symbolLocation": 0,
            "symbol": "_dispatch_continuation_cache_limit"
          },
          {
            "value": 1535
          },
          {
            "value": 7968254912,
            "symbolLocation": 1536,
            "symbol": "_dispatch_root_queues"
          },
          {
            "value": 50331647
          }
        ],
        "flavor": "ARM_THREAD_STATE64",
        "lr": {
          "value": 8357188472
        },
        "cpsr": {
          "value": 1073741824
        },
        "fp": {
          "value": 6099020080
        },
        "sp": {
          "value": 6099020048
        },
        "esr": {
          "value": 1442840704,
          "description": " Address size fault"
        },
        "pc": {
          "value": 7396030820,
          "matchesCrashFrame": 1
        },
        "far": {
          "value": 7924505944
        }
      },
      "queue": "com.apple.root.default-qos",
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 31076,
          "symbol": "__pthread_kill",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 0
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 29560,
          "symbol": "pthread_kill",
          "symbolLocation": 268,
          "imageIndex": 10
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 130896,
          "symbol": "abort",
          "symbolLocation": 164,
          "imageIndex": 14
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 80836,
          "symbol": "abort_message",
          "symbolLocation": 132,
          "imageIndex": 15
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 20440,
          "symbol": "demangling_terminate_handler()",
          "symbolLocation": 332,
          "imageIndex": 15
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 114228,
          "symbol": "_objc_terminate()",
          "symbolLocation": 144,
          "imageIndex": 16
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 77656,
          "symbol": "std::__terminate(void (*)())",
          "symbolLocation": 20,
          "imageIndex": 15
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 77556,
          "symbol": "std::terminate()",
          "symbolLocation": 64,
          "imageIndex": 15
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 18052,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_client_callout",
          "symbolLocation": 40,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 30616,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_queue_override_invoke",
          "symbolLocation": 792,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 89568,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_root_queue_drain",
          "symbolLocation": 396,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 91656,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_worker_thread2",
          "symbolLocation": 164,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 4280,
          "symbol": "_pthread_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 228,
          "imageIndex": 10
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 3732,
          "symbol": "start_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10159,
      "queue": "com.apple.NSURLSession-work",
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 7628,
          "symbol": "kevent_qos",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 0
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 159364,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_kq_poll",
          "symbolLocation": 172,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 158288,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_kq_drain",
          "symbolLocation": 188,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 156628,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_event_loop_poke",
          "symbolLocation": 160,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 313244,
          "imageIndex": 17
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 113848,
          "imageIndex": 17
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 147444,
          "imageIndex": 17
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 418496,
          "imageIndex": 17
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 418160,
          "imageIndex": 17
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 314528,
          "imageIndex": 17
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 147128,
          "imageIndex": 17
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 108864,
          "imageIndex": 17
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 116400,
          "imageIndex": 17
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 10532,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_call_block_and_release",
          "symbolLocation": 32,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 18032,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_client_callout",
          "symbolLocation": 20,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 48628,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_lane_serial_drain",
          "symbolLocation": 672,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 51612,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_lane_invoke",
          "symbolLocation": 444,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 94648,
          "symbol": "_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread",
          "symbolLocation": 656,
          "imageIndex": 11
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 4340,
          "symbol": "_pthread_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 288,
          "imageIndex": 10
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 3732,
          "symbol": "start_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "usedImages": [
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 7395999744,
      "size": 212992,
      "uuid": "eb3e47f3-3953-3583-9fee-fb6cff8a8d7a",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
      "name": "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6684622848,
      "size": 745472,
      "uuid": "b25ee3e7-26fd-35fb-84bb-af8b0f03e754",
      "path": "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/IOKit.framework\/Versions\/A\/IOKit",
      "name": "IOKit"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 7159754752,
      "size": 81920,
      "uuid": "75031460-c148-3d2e-af04-af10ccdf2dc8",
      "path": "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/IOSurface.framework\/IOSurface",
      "name": "IOSurface"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6709768192,
      "size": 933888,
      "uuid": "1185819b-01a1-3aeb-9c4f-f3224b2b7208",
      "path": "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/CoreUI.framework\/CoreUI",
      "name": "CoreUI"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6531493888,
      "size": 3043328,
      "uuid": "0594369d-11dd-39d9-a981-74984f490c0c",
      "path": "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/QuartzCore.framework\/QuartzCore",
      "name": "QuartzCore"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6505607168,
      "size": 25735168,
      "uuid": "cd7f7ba2-a2c6-3727-aff6-9baab60cc6ab",
      "path": "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
      "name": "UIKitCore"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6467174400,
      "size": 4538368,
      "uuid": "16faa70c-278c-3561-859e-cec407c2dc7c",
      "path": "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
      "name": "CoreFoundation"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6932385792,
      "size": 36864,
      "uuid": "064a1bb6-0e41-3ad2-a402-fb563fc141f5",
      "path": "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/GraphicsServices.framework\/GraphicsServices",
      "name": "GraphicsServices"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64",
      "base": 4371283968,
      "size": 6291456,
      "uuid": "12f279d1-f4df-3463-98f8-4ded371f9064",
      "path": "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/288BFDA2-6B20-4EC2-902A-CCBCAEFCE3BA\/MTGDiscover.app\/MTGDiscover",
      "name": "MTGDiscover"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 4382064640,
      "size": 360448,
      "uuid": "f94ccc7a-6d1a-33c7-997f-f611a6caa7e0",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
      "name": "dyld"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 8357158912,
      "size": 49152,
      "uuid": "c5c27e9d-9557-39c9-b9c6-5f6e7323ee1c",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
      "name": "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6464057344,
      "size": 290816,
      "uuid": "edd169e1-d0db-3808-a19e-99c1cd5a1c4c",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
      "name": "libdispatch.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6492483584,
      "size": 3174400,
      "uuid": "9618b2f2-a4c2-3e07-b7ee-d8d9e1bdeaec",
      "path": "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
      "name": "Foundation"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 8357269504,
      "size": 229376,
      "uuid": "4a0071bc-1b1f-3cbb-9602-72663b72e875",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libxpc.dylib",
      "name": "libxpc.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6650925056,
      "size": 520192,
      "uuid": "f3afe304-0979-3cba-8338-bebe9722ecd8",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
      "name": "libsystem_c.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6880083968,
      "size": 106496,
      "uuid": "71b1e39f-b291-315d-af46-a4343e707387",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/libc++abi.dylib",
      "name": "libc++abi.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6878994432,
      "size": 237568,
      "uuid": "73e920f0-e7ce-3941-97d8-7a10dd2cd390",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/libobjc.A.dylib",
      "name": "libobjc.A.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6475665408,
      "size": 5001216,
      "uuid": "b63d7160-ebc3-3de7-b98b-ca51e08b72f1",
      "path": "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CFNetwork.framework\/CFNetwork",
      "name": "CFNetwork"
    }
  ],
  "sharedCache": {
    "base": 6463733760,
    "size": 2504884224,
    "uuid": "c872bdab-4307-3f14-aef9-4af43391af25"
  },
  "vmSummary": "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=760.6M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=760.6M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=582.7M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=582.7M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nColorSync                           32K        2 \nCoreAnimation                       16K        1 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           577.5M       34 \nMALLOC guard page                  128K        8 \nSQLite page cache                   64K        1 \nSTACK GUARD                        128K        8 \nStack                             4816K        8 \nVM_ALLOCATE                        144K        1 \n__AUTH                            4088K      459 \n__AUTH_CONST                      22.6M      605 \n__DATA                            16.4M      592 \n__DATA_CONST                      24.2M      611 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      2177K      510 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       188.4M        4 \n__OBJC_CONST                      5897K      427 \n__OBJC_RO                         91.1M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3488K        1 \n__TEXT                           572.2M      623 \n__UNICODE                          588K        1 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nmapped file                       36.8M        8 \nshared memory                       48K        3 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.5G     3913 \n",
  "legacyInfo": {
    "threadTriggered": {
      "queue": "com.apple.root.default-qos"
    }
  },
  "trialInfo": {
    "rollouts": [
      {
        "rolloutId": "607844aa04477260f58a8077",
        "factorPackIds": {
          "SIRI_MORPHUN_ASSETS": "6103050cbfe6dc472e1c982a"
        },
        "deploymentId": 240000066
      },
      {
        "rolloutId": "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
        "factorPackIds": {},
        "deploymentId": 240000008
      },
      {
        "rolloutId": "602ad4dac86151000cf27e46",
        "factorPackIds": {
          "SIRI_DICTATION_ASSETS": "61ae8d06da72d16a4beb762e"
        },
        "deploymentId": 240000290
      },
      {
        "rolloutId": "602c34a3046661000c9ebdde",
        "factorPackIds": {
          "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_NL_OVERRIDES": "61dc8734b1ed363a74899478"
        },
        "deploymentId": 240000549
      },
      {
        "rolloutId": "5fc94383418129005b4e9ae0",
        "factorPackIds": {
          "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_ASR_HAMMER": "61dc87ef5c7f7c17c94020b9"
        },
        "deploymentId": 240000207
      },
      {
        "rolloutId": "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
        "factorPackIds": {
          "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH": "61c0d3122be4e338e11ae9e1"
        },
        "deploymentId": 240000362
      },
      {
        "rolloutId": "60509d56f2766876dee21c11",
        "factorPackIds": {
          "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_ASR_ASSISTANT": "61a69c56b1c7c7620ce6e458",
          "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_NL": "615b80614145ca7c40307b5c",
          "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_MORPHUN": "610072c2f6774779a7ced014",
          "SIRI_EXPERIENCE_CAM": "6149058343975f57daaf0657"
        },
        "deploymentId": 240000559
      },
      {
        "rolloutId": "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
        "factorPackIds": {},
        "deploymentId": 240000094
      }
    ],
    "experiments": [
      {
        "treatmentId": "06dd09ac-4929-4c36-8aa5-454eba81318c",
        "experimentId": "60cb9b8392f6a873b12a8ba6",
        "deploymentId": 400000038
      },
      {
        "treatmentId": "c4ac6461-f0e0-47b0-a630-f7739342ca3b",
        "experimentId": "60c785f07aa5af21f0101872",
        "deploymentId": 400000012
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To answer my own issue, the problem was I had a switch statement at the top level of my app that did not have a corresponding `break` a the end of the case.

Editing for clarity...

Here was the offending code:

```
  const dispatchEvent = (actionType, payload) => {
    switch (actionType) {
      case 'UPDATE_BADGE_COUNT':
        setBadgeCount(payload);
        break;
      case 'UPDATE_CARDS_MAP':
        setCardsMap(payload);
        break;
      case 'UPDATE_CARDS_ARRAY':
        setCardsArray(payload);
        break;
      case 'UPDATE_CARDS_FAVORITED':
        setCardsFavorited(payload);
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
```

`case 'UPDATE_CARDS_FAVORITED':` was missing a break and for some reason this was not throwing any issue unless the app was built and distributed via Test Flight.

Comment: It's great that you solved it, but this answer in no grows out of the information given in the question.

Comment: I addressed your note by adding the code that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on android and solved running expo doctor. The command failed to autocorrect library conflicts generated after sdk 46 update. So i used its log to manually search and uninstall conflicting libraries (that luckily i was not using anymore).
In the end for me this was a library conflict problem that showed up only when i run app from apk.